# Textview doesn't show up

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm making calculator UI layout 
The problem is id/num and id/name are not showing. Although I set those ones to be above the UI, but, it doesn't work. 
In blueprints, it only shows tiny horizontal line.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/calculator"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/calculator"/>


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/calculator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name">


        </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Please no HELP ME PLZ in your title.

Comment: @Julian it seems no problem in your xml.  Could you try to convert it via constraint layout. You more control on your layout if you go in that way.

Comment: i thinkg your `calculator` layout is over the `name` layout, so make your `calculator` layout under all the views that you make

Comment: My apology, I didn't know how to post in a propriate way since I'm new to this website : (

Comment: And I appreciate all you guys' comments thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There seems to be [a lot more code than what seems necessary for the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you see about trimming it down some, so we can better understand it? Also, while you're at it, could you add more details on what your specific problem is?

Comment: yup, sure thing! I can do that : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make a center in parent your `calculator` and put make `line` above that `calculator`
change this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/calculator"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/calculator"/>


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/calculator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name">
```

to this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/calculator" //here is a change
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/calculator"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/calculator"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="#000" />


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/calculator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">  //here is a change
```

if that you want to achieve

Comment: Holy Moly! your suggestion worked!! but still I don't understand why centerInParent in TableLayout should be happened. I thought it was fine to just use gravity: center in RelativeLayout(Parent one).  Could you please explain that if you don't mind?

Comment: ( and centerInParent made the work as i just wished)

Comment: @poream3387 setting `centerInParent` you tell to other views the position of your view, without setting it the `RelativeLayout` was drawing `line` in centerVertical (because u set gravity) and over that view you `calculator` also in the center.

Comment: so basically the view was there but it was behind `calculator`